# Lando runtime exception during installation

Tags: 9, installation

I keep getting the same error when trying to install Drupal locally on my Windows 10 Pro machine with Lando.

Steps to reproduce:

Install lando.exe on Windows 10 Pro, including bundled Docker

Download zip of https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project

Navigate to the directory where we extract the zip and run these commands in terminal:

```
$ lando init
$ lando composer install
```

Then we get this error:

```
 - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v5.4.1): Extracting archive
 139/140 [===========================>]  99%    Install of drupal/core failed



  [RuntimeException]

  Could not delete /app/vendor/composer/be1d725e/drupal-core-a5c83e4/misc/dialog:



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-suggest] [--no-dev] [--no-autoloader] [--no-progress] [--no-install] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Then I tried (to no avail) removing lines 22, 42 and 67-71 from composer.json (anything that refers to drupal-scaffold) as recommended in https://www.reddit.com/r/drupal/comments/f2p27o/comment/fic3vx6/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: Lando has a Drupal 9 template: https://www.specbee.com/blogs/getting-started-with-lando-and-drupal-9  Drupal also has baked-in support for composer now; there's no need to use drupal-composer/drupal-project for starting new projects: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/manage-dependencies#download-core

Comment: Check again after running `lando composer clear-cache` , seems packages are corrupted earlier.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with lando.

Comment: @PatrickKenny drupal-composer/drupal-project still much more mature then the recommended template IMHO

Comment: @leymannx, why more mature? Yes, it's much older, but now pretty much the same as the core recommended template, only with more features. I kind of agree with Patrick Kenny here. If you get an error with this 3rd party project then try the more basic core project or the one provided by Lando.

Comment: I'd rather switch to DDEV instead of switching the Composer template to one that's just for Lando.

Comment: @4uk4 – The recommended template doesn't include Drush, composer-patches and a script handler. The drupal-project simply comes with batteries included.